# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/3} \sin^2\frac{x}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We want to find the values of x for which the series :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  n^{1/3} \sin^2\frac{x}{n} $$ converges
(that's 3rd root of n in there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*By equivalents:*

$$\Bigl\lvert n^{1/3}\sin^2 \biggl(\frac {x}{n}\Bigr)\biggr\rvert\sim_\infty n^{1/3}\frac{x^2}{n^2}=\frac{x^2}{n^{5/3}},$$
which converges. Hence the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: it's the sine squared, not n

Comment: Sorry, I misread. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, for all $x$
$$
\lvert \sin x\rvert\le \lvert x\rvert,
$$
and hence
$$
n^{1/3}\sin^2\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)\le \frac{x^2}{n^{5/3}}.
$$
Therefore, the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/3}\sin^2\Big(\frac{x}{n}\Big)
$$
converges *absolutely* for every $x\in\mathbb R$, due to *Comparison Test*.

In fact, it converges *uniformly* on $x$, in every closed interval.